# SpriteKit Nodes appear smaller in iPhone 6 plus and iPhone 6s plus simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

In iPhone 6 Plus and 6s Plus simulator, the nodes in my GameScene look much smaller than how they're supposed to do (even though the screen fits perfectly - no black bars, empty space, ...).  Strangely, the nodes in my MenuScene and my TutorialScene (in the same simulator) are all normal-sized. My app runs perfectly (with normal-sized nodes in all Scenes) on all other simulators (iPad air, iPad pro, iPhone 5,5s,6,6s).
P
I've tried the following things:

- I create launch images for all sizes --> in App Icons and Launch Images, I migrate launch images to an asset catalog --> delete the line in the "launch screen file" --> doesn't work
- I tried the same thing above but this time I deleted the Launch Screen.storyboard (if I have created launch images for all iPhone sizes, why would I need this?)  --> doesn't work
- I delete my launch images and restore launch screen.storyboard (basically reset everything) --> doesn't work

What is wrong with my iPhone 6 Plus and iPhone 6s Plus simulator?

Comment: Can you clarify what GameScene etc are? Are they SpriteKit scenes, SceneKit scenes, something else?

Comment: They're all SpriteKit scenes

Comment: Do a basic debugging: print view size, print scene size, print problematic sprite size and its texture size. Check if scale factor on problematic sprites. Clear Simulators content and cache (look into simulator's menu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Problem solved! (but I still don't know how)

After testing my app on all simulators, I found out that the only devices in which my nodes appear smaller are iPhone 6+ and 6s+. These devices use 3x images. So I figured there's something wrong with my 3x images.

After checking, I didn't find anything wrong with those images (they were the exact same images as the 1x and 2x ones, except their names has the @3x suffix).

So I deleted all 3x images in my images.xcassets  --> problem solved

I still want to know how this solved my problem though. Please comment if you can explain it :)

Answer (score 0):

This might help,

The assets folder have 1x, 2x and 3x images. If you only have an image set in the 1x image then all devices will use that image and scale it appropriately.

If you have set the 2x and 3x images then the devices will use theses images but won't scale them.

The 2x image should be twice as big as the 1x image.
If your 1x image is 100px x 100px then your 2x image should be 200px x 200px.

The 3x image should be three times as big as the 1x image.
If your 1x image is 100px x 100px then your 3x image should be 300px x 300px

So you set the same image in all the 1x, 2x and 3x image boxes. So the device will use the right one for its screen size which will make it look smaller on the larger screen (iPhone 6s) because you haven't scaled them.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/image-size-and-resolution/) in iOS Human Interface Guidelines